# On the mac platform, how can I programmatically determine when a user logs in via an SSH session?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, unix

When I open a terminal (in linux or mac), I can use the command 'who' to see who is currently logged on. I would like to write a native mac application (either C or Objective-C) that informs me at the precise moment a user logs in (e.g. via SSH).

I have found this code here:
[SystemEventsMonitor.m](http://proteusim.googlecode.com/svn/tags/4.16/System%20Events/SystemEventsMonitor.m)

...which looks to be able to garner information about the desktop but it doesn't give anything away about logged on users. I have also found a link about [Login Hooks](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT2420) but what I need is a C or objective-C api.

So: how can I detect when a user logs in to my mac machine (via SSH or other means)?

Ben.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to poll on the command /usr/bin/users programmatically from objective-c using the NSTask class. Every 5 seconds, I check if any new users have logged in or out by parsing the command's output and comparing it to the currently stored state, adding new users to the state and displaying notifications if they're new (i.e. 'user logged in event'), or removing them and displaying notifications if they've logged out (i.e. 'user logged out event').

[Code on github here](https://github.com/benhj/OSXLoginNotifier)

Answer (score 0):

As You know the linux command `who` which is also available on Mac platform, you can use `system` call with this command as:

```
int main ()
{
    system("who");
    return 0;
}
```

Also you can use `w` command also.

Comment: Many thanks, but what I need is a 'trigger' of sorts. I.e. when the user logs in to my machine, I need this trigger to inform me that the user has logged in.

Comment: @BenJ If it is not a definite requirement for you to use C, you can use [crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) that can keep executing a simple script command which actually uses these linux commands like `who`.

Comment: @BenJ crontabs are meant to be non interactive, but you can make the script to return the output of the linux commands for you.